# Can Apache solr stores actual files which are uploaded on it?

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, apache-tika

This is my first time on Stack Overflow. Thanks to all for providing valuable information and helping one another.

I am currently working on Apache Solr 7. There is a POC I need to complete as I have less time so putting this question here. I have setup SOLR on my windows machine. I have created core and uploaded a PDF document using /update/extract from Admin UI. After uploading, I can see the metadata of the file if I query from the Admin UI using query button. I was wondering if I can get the actusl content of the PDF as well. I can see there is one tlog file gets generated under /data/tlog/tlog000... with raw PDF data but not the actual file.

So the question are, 
1. Can I get the PDF content?
2. does Solr stores the actual file somewhere?
     a. If it stores then where it does?
     b. If it does not store then, is there a way to store THE FILE?

Regards,
Munish Arora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr will not sore the actual file anywhere.
Depending on your config it can store the binary content though.
Using the extract request handler Apache Solr relies on Apache Tika[1] to extract the content from the document[2].

So you can search and return the content of the pdf and a lot of other metadata if you like.

[1] https://tika.apache.org/

[2] https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/uploading-data-with-solr-cell-using-apache-tika.html

Comment: Thank you Alessandro Benedetti for clearing my doubt.